# "Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что он не относится к программированию."

Tags: обсуждение, метки

Не совсем понимаю, может кто-нибудь объяснит?

Есть 2 вопроса:

1. [Не могу поставить Windows 7 после Ubuntu с флешки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/578644/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%83-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-windows-7-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5-ubuntu-%D1%81-%D1%84%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%B8/578673#comment767016_578673)
2. [Можно ли использовать дочерние элементы в h1? [закрыто]](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/575447/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%B2-h1)

Первый вопрос с программированием не связан **вообще** никак.
Второй вопрос, если судить грубо и беспристрастно, тоже не связан с программированием (HTML - это не ЯП, как, в общем-то, и SEO). Но если посудить с другой стороны, то второй вопрос куда больше подходит тематике сайта, нежели первый.

Для меня остается загадкой то, почему второй вопрос закрыли с пометкой *"Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что он не относится к программированию."*, а первый, хотя связан с программированием он намного меньше, чем второй, остается открытым. Где логика?

И еще, попутно. Если здесь запрещено задавать вопросы, связанные с программированием, то зачем вообще нужны теги, которые к программированию не относятся?

Возьмем для примера тот же тег *Windows-7*. Вы можете сказать, что он может понадобиться в связке с другим тегом, например "*Программа на <вставьте ЯП> не запускается на Windows 7.*". Но я не думаю, что кто-то будет искать подобный вопрос по тегу *Windows-7*. А ведь теги для того и предназначены, чтобы по ним что-то искали.

Нечто подобное можно сказать и про тег *железо* (hardware). Если это сайт для вопросов о **программировании**, то зачем здесь тег железо, когда вопросам по этим тегам чаще всего минусуют, или вообще их закрывают? Спасибо.

Comment: Второй вопрос не про то, можно ли помещать один тег в другой, а про допустимость этого с точки зрения SEO. Такие вопросы не в почете.

Comment: Метки операционных систем используются для ОС-специфичных вопросов (системное администрирование - онтопик). Метка [tag:железо] может применяться для вопросов, связанных с embedded устройствами и администрированием.

Comment: И, кстати, HTML - это ЯП. Вопросы именно по HTML (без SEO) - онтопик.

Comment: @PashaPash Если очень-очень формально, то да, тогда и XML язык программирования и CSS тоже, но все-таки буква M отражает, что это язык разметки - Markup. Официальные стандарты W3C называют его языком разметки и упоминания Programming даже нет, в отличии от других, где явно указано, что например C++ Programming Language (ISO/IEC 14882:2014). Правильнее считать, что HTML принадлежит к классу компьютерных языков.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Дополню комментарий [@Nofate](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/1984/nofate).

Есть вероятность, что первый вопрос относится к системному администрированию. Такие вопросы [допустимы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) на сайте, согласно выбору, сделанному сообществом. Второй вопрос не относится к программированию, вопрос про SEO-оптимизацию. Такие вопросы недопустимы и должны закрываться как нетематические.

Comment: А где решили, что seo должно закрываться? o_O

Comment: @Qwertiy [В вопросе, определяющем тематику сайта.](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/107/)

Comment: Seo там не ищется.

Comment: @Qwertiy Формулировка определяет, какие вопросы являются _тематическими_ для сайта. Все, что туда не попало, является не тематическим.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky: а что насчёт вопросов насчёт понимания каких-то фундаментальных знаний? Например вроде этого - http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/357931/Зачем-нужен-ip-адрес-если-есть-mac-адрес. Он не относится ни к программированию, ни к настройке, ни к реальной проблеме, но разве такие вопросы должны закрываться?

Comment: @МАН69К Этот вопрос можно вполне отнести к администрированию.